# Representations of the Poincaré group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, representation-theory, commutator, poincare-symmetry

I am currently trying to understand the representations of the conformal group. I am following the [script by J. D. Qualls](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04074).

At page 29, the author finds the effect of $L_{\mu\nu}$ by "studying the Lorentz group–the subgroup of the
Poincaré group that leaves the point $x = 0$ invariant", and postulates: $L_{\mu\nu}\Phi(0)=S_{\mu\nu}\Phi(0)$. He uses here the Hausdorff formula
\begin{align}
    e^{ix^{\lambda}P_{\lambda}}L_{\mu\nu}e^{-ix^{\lambda}P_{\lambda}}
     &=L_{\mu\nu}-x_\mu P_\nu+x_\nu P_\mu   
\end{align}
and then concludes that
\begin{align}
    P_\mu\Phi(x)&=-i\partial_\mu \Phi(x)  \\
    L_{\mu\nu}\Phi(x)&=(i(x_\mu\partial_\nu - x_\nu \partial_\nu) +S_{\mu\nu})\Phi(x).
\end{align}
I am having trouble understanding the reasoning here. I tried to derive the $P_\mu$ by
\begin{align}
\Phi(x)&=e^{-ix^{\lambda}P_{\lambda}}\Phi(0) \\
\partial_\mu\Phi(x)&=-iP_{\mu}e^{-ix^{\lambda}P_{\lambda}}\Phi(0) \\
&\implies P_\mu=i\partial_\mu
\end{align}
Already here I don't find a minus in front of the derivative (for the expression of $P_{\mu}$). I tought,whether the equation   $\Phi(x)=e^{-ix^{\lambda}P_{\lambda}}\Phi(0)$ had to be $\Phi(x)=e^{ix^{\lambda}P_{\lambda}}\Phi(0)$. If I do that way, I find the equation for $P_\mu$ right, but then I find  $L_{\mu\nu}\Phi(x)=(-i(x_\mu\partial_\nu - x_\nu \partial_\nu) +S_{\mu\nu})\Phi(x)$
Is my calculation here wrong? If so, what is the right method?

My second question related to this topic would be the following: Some references like https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982 uses commutators to describe the same problem as (page 16, Poincare Representations)
$$
[M_{\mu\nu},\mathcal{O}^a(0)]=(S_{\mu\nu})^a_b\mathcal{O}^b(0)
$$
Why are here now commutators used? How is it related to the first description? Are they the same description, but is the Heisenberg picture hidden in the first description? I am quite new in the field theories in general and I would appreciate any help.

I am aware that there is a possible duplicate  [Derivation of the full generator of the Lorentz transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119647/), but I did not quite understand the derivations and reasoning there.

Comment: The coordinate dependence of a function always transforms under the inverse representation as the components, hence the minus sign. The commutator is basically just the Poisson bracket. The Noether charge associated with a sym. generates that sym. via the bracket.

Comment: Your second question is the leading commutator in Hadamard's lemma. You've already been there, and your reference is crushingly explicit about it.

Comment: Note that when operators transform as $M \mapsto U M U^{-1}$, the change of basis matrix affecting the states is $U$, not $U^{-1}$.